# Azure Caching Platform Options - What Are The Alternatives?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-caching

I'm currently building a site that will be hosted in Microsoft Azure. The last site I created in this hosting environment used "Windows Azure Shared Caching". Some of you may already be aware that "Windows Azure Shared Caching" service will soon be deprecated over the next year.

I have applied for the preview release of "Windows Azure Cache". However, I'm finding that my request is still "queued".

I wouldn't mind using "Windows Azure Shared Caching" since the site I'm building will only be live for around 10 weeks and the fact it being deprecated next year doesn't worry me. However, I am unable to create a new caching service through the old Azure Management Portal since new caching has to be done using "Windows Azure Cache".

So my question...

Since my application for the new caching platform is still yet to be approved and I am unable to create a new caching service under the old platform, what other options are there? Have I missed something?

Microsoft is surely making things difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other option you have is using [In-Role Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx#In_RoleCache) for Web/Worker roles ([Azure Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/)). Any role [within the same cloud deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn386103.aspx) can access the cache. If you have just 1 web role - this acts very similar to ASP.NET State Server which provides an in-memory cache. However, as you add more web roles - you can choose to distribute this in-memory cache across all roles or use a dedicate worker role for managing the cache.

**Dedicated In-Role Cache:** worker role uses all available memory 
**Co-Located In-Role Cache:** percentage of available memory is used across all roles

See [In-Role Cache FAQ on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914142.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I forgot to state that I'm building a site using Azure for Websites not using the cloud services. If what you've stated in your post is the only way to get some sort of caching, then that's the route I'll have to take. Do you know if there is any caching options specifically for Azure for Websites?

Comment: If you are using **Azure Websites** then you must use **Shared Caching** or **Cache Service (Preview)**. Otherwise - you need to use **Azure Cloud Service** until you get approved for the Cache Service Preview. I applied yesterday and got approved for the Cache Service immediately (*cache.windows.net*). Are you using a paid, trial, or MSDN Azure subscription?

Comment: I have a paid Azure subscription. Since **Cache Service** is currently in preview, is there anything I need to be concerned about due to the fact its not a proper release?

Comment: I have used many of the **Preview Features** (*websites, CDN, service bus, media service, VMs*) with great success since Azure's inception. I would recommend using the **Cache Service**.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your request should have been approved (irrespective of whether yours is a paid/trial/free subscription). If it still hasn't, put the query up [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/home?forum=azurecache). This is the forum for Cache.
2. This is a proper release of the Cache Service! The core is very mature and Microsoft is giving great support on top of it. Go ahead and use it!
3. This flavor of Cache is THE right one for Azure Websites.

Leave a post at the forum for any concerns/issues you have. It is being constantly monitored and replied to.

Comment: Forgot to add, the deprecation of the Shared Caching Service implies that no new caches can be created there, and the service is available for a certain period of time for the existing customers. 
All existing customers are being asked to switch to the new service, a process that we have tried to make as seamless as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I am the first to suggest [Azure Redis Caching](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/)?